# $x + xy + z^2 = 3$ and $x^3 + 2xy − y^2z^2 = 2$ is the graph of a smooth map

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Prove that the solution set $S$ of equations $x + xy + z^2 = 3$ and $x^3 + 2xy − y^2z^2 = 2$ is the graph of a smooth map $\gamma : I \to R^2$ in a neighborhood of $(1, 1, 1)$, where $I \subset R$ is open.

Need Hint how to apply Inverse/Implicit Function Theorem.